# What is the difference between using a Kalman filter and just recursively applying the Bayes rule as new data comes in?

Tags: bayesian, kalman-filter

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the Kalman filter: Is it just Bayes rule applied over and over with each new measurement? Or is there more to it?

Comment: The more to it is that the hidden state can evolve and all the observations etc... are conditionally normal. A process is Markov if the past is independent of the future given the present. A hidden markov model is a Markov process where the state variable isn't directly observed. With a Bayesian filter, you use Bayes rule to update beliefs about the hidden state given observations. The Kalman filter is a Bayes filter where basically everything follows the normal distribution.